# How to include a regular View and FlatList on the same page that scroll with each other?

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a design where the page has a top "header" image and a list of items underneath it. I've put the top header in its own View and the list into a FlatList. I need to use a FlatList here because the list is paginated and I want to make use of the `onEndReached` functionality.

The issue I'm facing is that if I don't wrap everything in a `ScrollView` then the top header acts like a sticky item. However if I do wrap everything in a `ScrollView` and set the FlatList to `scrollEnabled={false}` then it works but the `onEndReached` callback no longer fires.

Here is a snack that illustrates what I don't want to happen but where the `onEndReached` callback works.

https://snack.expo.dev/@ktranel101/brave-churros

Here is a snack that illustrates what I do want to happen but the `onEndReached` callback does not work.

https://snack.expo.dev/@ktranel101/thankful-ice-cream

Comment: Move the header to `ListHeaderComponent` of `FlatList`

Comment: @DinhNguyen thank you, that was what I needed. If you answer the question I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the header to `ListHeaderComponent` of `FlatList`:

```
<FlatList
   data={imgs}
   renderItem={({item}) => {
     return (
       <View
         style={styles.thumbnail}>
         <ImageBackground resizeMode='cover' style={styles.thumbnailImg} source={{uri : item}}>
         </ImageBackground>
       </View>
     )
   }
   ListHeaderComponent={() => (
     <View
       style={styles.thumbnail}>
       <ImageBackground resizeMode='cover' style={styles.thumbnailImg} source={{uri : 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/treo-dev/3d4921d2-a5c2-4040-a539-c2aaafac36ac/c8f66690-2fed-11ee-b91f-3b644dc34d01.jpg'}}>
       </ImageBackground>
     </View>
   )}
/>
```